# Query in mySQL to select 44 questions from each 'purpose' 11 in random order PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table where I have to fetch questions, in random order from each category 11 from 4 different categories.

Something like this: Select * limited to 44 from 'questions' where 11 are from each 'purpose' in random order.
The table looks something like this:

[image]

What I've done so far is this:

```
$questions = Question::take(44)->inRandomOrder()->get();
```

But it only get's 44 questions where some category get's more then others.

Comment: are categories a separate table? and questions having a category_id?

Comment: add category table in questioh @key

Comment: @FatemehMajd, no 'categories' represents the 'purpose' column. I need information only from this table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$questions = collect();
$questions = $questions->merge(Question::where('purpose', 'purpose-1')->take(11)->inRandomOrder()->get());
$questions = $questions->merge(Question::where('purpose', 'purpose-2')->take(11)->inRandomOrder()->get());
$questions = $questions->merge(Question::where('purpose', 'purpose-3')->take(11)->inRandomOrder()->get());
$questions = $questions->merge(Question::where('purpose', 'purpose-4')->take(11)->inRandomOrder()->get());
$questions = $questions->shuffle();
```

Comment: This works, but it's very slow. thanks anyways. let's see if we can optimize this

Comment: How big the table is? Did you indexed purpose column? To make it faster you should change the table structure, or run one complex query instead of 4. The complex query may not make it fast as you expect

Comment: Although the question did not mention slowness / fastness you may write a raw query by using group by. It is better to ask another question to expect written raw queries

Comment: And if it worked, the answer deserves to be accepted, please

Answer (score 0):

three ways come to my mind:

1- union four different tables. for this way, I suggest you first get all the purposes distinctively and shuffle them you can also use the RANDOm query, but that's a really slow query command.

```
$fourPurposes =Question::select('purpose')->get()->shuffle()->flatten()->unique();

$unions = Question::query();
for(%i=0;$i<4;$i++){
  $query = Question::where('prupose', $fourPurposes[$i])->limit(11);
  $unions = $unions->union($query);
}
$questions = $unions->get();
```

2- this is complicated, but if you have very big tables and have purpose column indexed, I think this would be the best. In this method, you join questions table with another questions table. In one, you limit purpose, in the other, you limit question count. The query should be something like this. (I am really not sure of it, I hope we can edit it to make it better)

```
$table1 = DB::table('questions')->groupBy('purpose')->limit(4);
$questions = DB::table('questions as q1)
->join(Db::raw('
  (select * from questions as q2 limit 11)
'), function($join){ 
      $join->on('q1.purpose','=','q2.purpose');
   })->limit(44)->get();
```

3- I think this one is the best method generally. If you do not have a massive table, use this one. It's a lot less complicated and a lot easier. In this method, you simply have four distinct queries. It's a lot like the first method, but simpler.

```
$fourPurposes =Question::select('purpose')->get()->shuffle()->flatten()->unique();

$questions =  new Collection();

for(%i=0;$i<4;$i++){
  $query = Question::where('prupose', $fourPurposes[$i])->limit(11)->get();
  $questions = $questions->union($query);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the first one and got an error "Undefined offset: 2"
and the third one said "Method getBindings does not exist."

Comment: i'm sorry but this does not work. the query is unstable and does not work every time. At times it does work, it doesn't limit the questions to 44 it just creates 2 queries where one just selects the table, and the other creates unions as needed. any idea?